# JavaScript - Flawed Calculator Using Google as Example

Tags: javascript, html, dom

As you can see on Google conversion at: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=feet%20to%20inches)

When you click the second drop down box and choose meters, Instead of it staying at 12 meters, it converts to .3048 meters, which isn't what I want. I want it so that when you change to meters on the right drop down box, it stays as 12 meters and the box on the left updates to 39.3701 feet. [Here](https://codepen.io/CoolBuys1290/pen/LYNajXQ) is my code so far.

```
var units = [['Inches', 0.025400000000000], ['Feet', 0.30480000000000000], ['Furlongs', 201.168], ['Meters', 1.00]];
 var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.newClass1');
 
 for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
     var option = document.createElement('option');
     option.value = units[i][1];
     option.textContent = units[i][0];
     selectors[j].add(option);
   }
 }
 
    function calcLength1() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value);
  document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value = SpecialValue;
   
}

function calcLength2() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value);
  document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value = SpecialValue;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
    <p>From:</p>
    <select style="float:left" id="lengthCalc1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="calcLength2()" onchange="calcLength2()">
    </select>
    <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="lengthInput1" type="number" oninput="calcLength1()" />
    <p>To:</p>
    <select style="float:left" id="lengthCalc2" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="calcLength1()" onchange="calcLength1()">   
    </select>
    <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="lengthInput2" type="number" oninput="calcLength2()" onchange="calcLength2()" />
</div>
```

It's completely flawed. Please help me make a good calculator.

Comment: your page doesn't even accept metres so .... how can we possibly duplicate your problem

Comment: Can you add your html as well?

Comment: Added HTML and included meters.

Comment: Looks like you're not converting the option value into number before doing the math. Can you use `parseFloat` to convert them and try if it works? Like `parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value)`.

Comment: Now code doesn't do anything. Updated parseFloat code. Check my CodePen @ https://codepen.io/CoolBuys1290/pen/LYNajXQ

Comment: You now have an error in your code check the console. You don't need to use parseFloat in the left hand side in the assignment. 
For instance: you don't need it here  `document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value = SpecialValue;`

Comment: Check the updated code, I posted below and see if it works.

Comment: I included your code, and there is still the same bug. See the comment to the answer you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:  To make the converter function properly same as the [google length converter](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=feet%20to%20inches), you can try the following:**

1. Update the second input box value when either of the of the dropdown of units changes.
2. Update the first input box when the second input box is changed, and vice-versa.

This means, your first input box value will update only when the user changes the value of the second input. Try it on the google's converter, it behaves the same way.

Use the following code to make it work.

```js
var units = [
  ['Inches', 0.025400000000000],
  ['Feet', 0.30480000000000000],
  ['Furlongs', 201.168],
  ['Meters', 1.00]
];
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.newClass1');

for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = units[i][1];
    option.textContent = units[i][0];
    selectors[j].add(option);
  }
}

function updateInputBox2() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value);

  document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value = SpecialValue;

}

function updateInputBox1() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value);

  document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value = SpecialValue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <p>From:</p>
  <select style="float:left" id="lengthCalc1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="updateInputBox2()" onchange="updateInputBox2()">
  </select>
  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="lengthInput1" type="number" oninput="updateInputBox2()" />
  <p>To:</p>
  <select style="float:left" id="lengthCalc2" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="updateInputBox2()" onchange="updateInputBox2()">
  </select>
  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="lengthInput2" type="number" oninput="updateInputBox1()" onchange="updateInputBox1()" />
</div>
```

**First problem with the conversion (outdated)**

Convert the values to number correctly and it should work. You have few typos in your code and also there's a left hand assignment error. Look at this line in your code, there are two errors:

```
  parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value) = praseFloat(SpecialValue);
```

**Try this, it should work.**

```
function calcLength1() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value);
  
  document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value = SpecialValue;
   
}

function calcLength2() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value);
  
  document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value = SpecialValue;
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists. Say I put in 12 inches on top box and feet on bottom box. The first calculation is correct. That 12 inches equal one foot. But when I change the Foot box on the bottom to Meters, I want it to stay as 1, and have it be 1 Meter equaling 39.37 inches on top, but instead of doing that, it converts the bottom box to .3048 Meters which does equal 12 inches, but I wanted 1 meter to stay as 1 meter and the top box to update. The Google convert tool has the same bug. Javascript code is needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Neo You need to decide which box gets the updated value when the select dropdown changes. With your logic right now, when your first select box is updated it will trigger change to the second input box, and when your second select box changes it will update the first input box -- isn't that your expected behavior? If yes, then your description matches exactly like what you've expected. Check your html and the functions they trigger. If this is not what you wanted then you should try for the reverse, try that.

Comment: Or, if you're to simplify it a bit then you should only update one input box regardless of which dropdown is changed. This will be intuitive UX wise too, because this way the first box is always the input and second is always the result, i.e only the result box changes. See the google calculator, it does the same way.

Comment: What code do I use to do this? I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do what? Please clearly state your requirement and I can help you address that.

Comment: When I change units, I want the value in the text box to stay the same. The code you posted as an answer doesn't do this. I want it so both text boxes have this attribute.I can't figure out what Javascript code that accomplishes this task. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: How do I respond to an event such as a drop down being selected?

Comment: @Neo I made an update, check my above code and run the snippet. I updated to make it behave the same way as google calculator. It is the only predictable way to do so w/o making confusing for the user. Try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: I need the second box to  update the first one when I change a unit in the second drop down box. Google's calculator has this flaw. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a flaw, Google made it intentionally - it's the least confusing way for the user and better UX IMO.If you don't want to go that way, then the issue will persist in yours. Read my comments above to see why it's confusing. Otherwise, try doing it yourself taking my code as a reference.

Comment: Sorry you were right about the UI making sense. Thanks a lot!